# Building native apps for different platforms using Xamarin?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

Lately , I have been given the role of the team leader in the mobile unit in my company. We are developing for iOS and Android, and we can expand it further more to Windows phone and Blackberry. The idea is to build native apps for different platforms. So the basic task is to choose in what platform we are going to develop. Of course we can have different programmers for different platforms but we don't want to go that way. So we are trying to choose a single cross compile platform for developing apps in multiple platforms.

One of the suggestion was  using Xamarin (https://xamarin.com).

Can you please tell me what are your pros and cons about this solution or any other suggestion that you find useful. We do not want to use HTML5 or any JavaScript approach.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This website is for asking specific, detailed programming questions. For very broad, opinion based questions like this, you should refer to forums or chat rooms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick : "Xamarin Pros and Cons" on Google leaded me to many results. At the end your team will have to make the decision.

http://www.intellicore.co.uk/articles/4-pros-and-cons-of-mono-touch

http://www.whitneyland.com/2013/05/why-i-dont-recommend-xamarin-for-mobile-development.html

https://www.linkedin.com/groups/What-is-benefit-disadvantages-using-121874.S.5848849341191569409

You should try it next time. I also suggest you to try their framework with the free version, see how it suits your team.

Comment: Both of these are OLD NEWS with Xamarin.Forms

Comment: @StenPetrov It doesn't make them wrong, anyway as I said, the best for him would be to try their free version.

Comment: Indeed it does. The articles talk about UI code being different for iOS vs Android - not so much the case any more and that was a major hurdle. These articles are from over a year ago, Xamarin.Forms is only a couple months old

Comment: @StenPetrov You are right, I had the impression he wanted an overview of the whole package, not a single feature. Feel free to add any new relevant link in my post :)